# Checking the time difference between two php DateTime objects

Tags: php, datetime

I am checking a difference between two timestamps returned from a database. Here is the code I'm using for this:

```
$startDate = new \DateTime($last14[$item]->started);
$endDate = new \DateTime($last14[$item]->finished);
$interval = $startDate->diff($endDate);
```

This returns the DateInterval object and it is correct.

Now the problem is I need to count all occurrences of the difference being over 13 hours. 13 hours dead is OK but 13 hours and 1 minutes needs counting. I have created a messy nested if lump:

```
if ($interval->h > 12) {
    if ($interval->i > 0) {
        $count++;
    } else {
        if ($interval->h > 13) {
            $count++;
        }
    }   
}
```

This appears to work but I was wondering if there is a better (cleaner) method of doing this. I have considered converting the time difference to minutes and just doing:

```
if ($minutes > $minutesIn13Hours) {
    $count++;
}
```

but that's another conversion step.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($interval->h * 60 + $interval->i > 13*60) {
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: why add the extra step of multiplying the 13 by 60. That will always be fixed so surely greater than 780 would be better?

Comment: Days, months and years will never be an issue as the time difference is never allowed to be over 23 hours.

Comment: because 780 is like magic number. It's not easy for understand what does it mean.

Comment: your answer is the same as mine apart from using 60 instead of 100 which makes no difference for the outcome. With 100 it is just easier to read. And @Gavin is right, no need to calculate something you already know.

Comment: No, it's not easier if we don't use a decimal time

Answer (score 0):

You will have less conditions to check if you do something like this:

```
if ( ($interval->h * 100) + $interval->i > 1300 ) {
            $count++;
}
```

Comment: please guys, stop editing my post. I am using 100 on purpose, not to mimic hours/minutes, but to get an easy number to check against.

Comment: I understand now I've had a closer look. Although for me, It's obvious it's calculating time so 60 seems a more logical number to use.

Comment: It is just for comparison, it is not going to be used in a calculation where hours are needed. To me >1300 is more clear than >780. The system is the same though.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the most clean, most readable and hopefully faster way of doing what you ask is this:

```
if (($interval->h > 12 && $interval->i > 0) || $interval->h > 13) {
  $count++;
}
```

Though, I suppose it will not be much faster than your first solution (if it **is** faster...).

*P.S.: Probably @RST solution will be a even little faster, but, since you ask for a cleaner solution, this is for sure more clear...*

Comment: I think your code will count 12 hours and 1-59 minutes too

Comment: Yes, thanks! I was thinking about 12 hours, not 13... :-( Corrected my answer, already...

Answer (score 0):

Or simply add 13 hours to start date then compare to end date.

```
if($endDate > $startDate->add(new DateInterval('PT13H'))) {
    $count++; // got it
}
```

More clean, readable, reliable, and safer. Probably better (in speed) than diff, btw.

Comment: The reason I'm using diff instead of add is that I need the time difference for another operation. Your right though, add I believe is faster than diff for straight forward comparisons.